# Lambda did not automatically deduce return type

Tags: c++, lambda, return-type, type-deduction

When I answewred my own question on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115498/383779 , I got another doubt.

In

```
const CArray<CItem*>& Items=
    (ItemsInput!= nullptr)?
        *ItemsInput
    :
        [this]() -> const CArray<CItem*>&
        {
            CArray<CItem*> InnerItems;
            GetContainer().GetInnerItems(InnerItems, NULL, true);
            return (InnerItems);
        } ()
;
```

I tried to remove the `-> const CArray<CItem*>&` return part, but it gave two errors when compiling:

```
1>FunctionClass.cpp(line of last semicolon): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'const CArray<TYPE> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=CItem *
1>          ]
1>          Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types


1>FunctionClass.cpp(line of the return statement): error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value
```

Can somebody explain why? Wasn't is supposed for the lambda to automatically deduce the type to be returned from its return statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620098/420683 Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955478/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/14450608/

Comment: You can't return a reference (`const` or not) to a local variable. See e.g. [this old question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1465851/440558).

Comment: Also see [Is my book's discussion of lamba return types wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14738335), [When can we omit the return type in a C++11 lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955478), [Why do lambda functions drop deduced return type reference by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41534031) and [Explicit Return Type of Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620098).

Answer (score 6):

From C++11 standard (N3242 5.1.2/4 it's really old specification)

> **If a lambda-expression does not include a trailing-return-type, it is
> as if the trailing-return-type denotes the following type**:
>
> — if the
> compound-statement is of the form
>
> { attribute-specifier-seq opt return expression ; }
>
> the type of the returned expression after
> lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion
> (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
>
> **— otherwise, void.**

since your lambda is not just return expression, return-type is void.

This is considered a defect in C++11 ([DR-985](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#975)) and many compilers have relaxed those restrictions to the C++14 even in C++11 mode (thanks @dyp).

Comment: Thanks. But the link for DR-985 is actually "975. Restrictions on return type deduction for lambdas". So it is DR-975, not DR-985.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile with C++14 support for that to work in cases where the body is more than just a return statement. What compiler and version are you using?

In any case, why do you return (InnerItems) instead of InnerItems ? Is it to explicitly return a reference to that local variable?

Comment: The error messages suggest the OP is using MSVC, which doesn't have any language standard switches AFAIK.

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2013 with the Visual C++ 2010 compilation toolkit, so it is not even yet C++11, and even less it could ever be C++14!

Comment: @sergiol Maybe you should consider switching to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Blacktempel I wish I could update. However, the decision to evolve to Visual Studio 2015 is not on my shoulders. When working in a software house, bosses want to minimize stability risk. So, they wait for calmer work periods and for a moment when the rest of the world has already tested the new version of a fundamental software piece.

Comment: @sergiol That may be true, but upgrading will bring a lot of improvements, performance and C++11 / C++14 features. The decision may not be in your hands, but nothing holds you from a great suggestion. Maybe deliver an update and right after it / meanwhile target the upgrade of your solution(s). I'm sure your customers wouldn't mind a performance increase and/or new features.